# problem with high usage of CPU in Django and Celery Docker images

Tags: django, docker, celery

I have multi-container application that I am running using Docker. Below is the list of containers I am using:

1. Django-app (postgresql as db and redis as broker)
2. Nginx
3. Celery-worker-1
4. Celery-worker-2
5. Celery-worker-3
6. Celery-beats
7. React currently it is stored on S3 bucket.

The problem I am facing is that my each celery task is triggering playwright chrominium engine to gather some data frp, websites and the CPU usage of each worker exceeds 200%. Moreover it affects Django app container where CPU usage exceeds 50% if I run more than 8 tasks in celery on localhost.

I am aware of the fact that celery has to comunicate with Django somehow therefore the CPU usage might increase but I want to scale up my application and I am trying to figure out how to decrease the CPU usage of each container. I wouldn't bother with CPU usage but when I trigger multiple tasks simutaneously my backend slows down dramatically (I need to wait up to 20 seconds to get any response on localhost).

I am planning to use AWS Fargate for my django app and EC2 with auto-scalling enabled for my celery workers and I am worried how this will work if I set up multiple tasks.

**Question**

What would you recommend to keep Django app alive and fast if I want to run multiple, heavy tasks that are running for more than 30 minutes. What I want to avoid is situation where I run multiple workers in multiple containers and my Django container will give up or will be slow and users will not be able to use the page at all.